# How to obtain values without key of dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase

```
var dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["title" : "Berlin",
"description" : "Berlin square",
"createdBy": "Mathias",
"coordinates": ["fddfhsg": ["latitude": 56.34, "longitude": 53.44]]]
```

`dictionary["coordinates"]`

I need to obtain values latitude and longitude, but I don't key ("fddfhsg") of dictionary. This key is generates by Firebase database.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I noticed you included the firebase tag in your question, but it's not mentioned how the data is being retrieved and the dictionary populated? Is it by running a firebase query and building the dictionary from a snapshot?

Answer (score 6):

You can get these values without knowing this key: cast "coordinates" to the right dictionary type then use optional binding and the `values` property.

Example:

```
if let dict = dictionary["coordinates"] as? [String:[String:Double]],
        content = dict.values.first,
        latitude = content["latitude"],
        longitude = content["longitude"] {
    print(latitude)
    print(longitude)
}
```

> 56.34
>   53.44

---

As an update after your comments: all you need to do now is to adapt to different dictionary structures.

For your second dictionary, look how it is structured:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary2 {
    print(key)
    print(value)
    print("---")
}
```

The values you're looking for are not at the same level than the other ones we grabbed previously.

Adapt the solution I've already given: it's only a matter of hierarchy in the dictionary. In `dictionary1` the unknown key was in "coordinates", but this one is at the root level.

Comment: Thank you very much! Huge help!

Comment: @Z.S. If that answer was the answer make sure you accept it! If it wasn't you may want to consider modifying your question with more data.